# ¿Cómo determino el promedio de replicas en un data frame?

Tags: r

Tengo un bucle `for` de **réplicas**. El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
df1<-data.frame(a,b,repl,c,d)
result1<-rbind(result1,df1)
result1
     a    b   repl  c     d
1  0.1   10    1   1 -0.003278261
2  0.1   10    1   2 -0.303283860
3  0.1   10    2   1 -0.025801369
4  0.1   10    2   2 -0.493055524
5  0.1  100    1   1  0.022530623
6  0.1  100    1   2  0.018299374
7  0.1  100    2   1  0.027534172
8  0.1  100    2   2  0.020472938
9  0.2   10    1   1 -0.193742837
10 0.2   10    1   2 -0.013846283
11 0.2   10    2   1 -0.208462537
12 0.2   10    2   2 -0.027364528
13 0.2  100    1   1 -0.094725184
14 0.2  100    1   2 -0.238462548
15 0.2  100    2   1 -0.391725489
16 0.2  100    2   2 -0.094725172
```

Como son réplicas, necesito obtener el **promedio** según **c**, para poder obtener algo así:

```
    a    b     c     d
1  0.1   10    1 -0.00481638
2  0.1   10    2 -0.43763283
3  0.1  100    1  0.42836484
4  0.1  100    2  0.43927372
5  0.2   10    1 -0.19384728
6  0.2   10    2 -0.12384719
7  0.2  100    1 -0.09472648
8  0.2  100    2 -0.22482749
```

Utilicé `colMeans(result1)` pero  me da el promedio general de cada columna, y yo busco el promedio de c según las réplicas. También utilicé el `apply (result1, 2, mean)` pero me resulta lo mismo que usar colMeans.

Espero puedan ayudarme porfavor! Gracias! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que  necesitas generar el promedio agrupado  por diferentes columnas.En el resultado que muestras agrupas los resultados por las columnas a,b y c , y aplicas alguna función a la columna d, por lo que el resultado lo agrupare por estas variables

```
library(dplyr)
a<-c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)
b<-c(10,10,10,10,100,100,100,100,10,10,10,10,100,100,100,100)
repl<-c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)
c<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
d<-c(-0.003278261,-0.30328386,-0.025801369,-0.493055524,0.022530623
    ,0.018299374,0.027534172,0.020472938,-0.193742837,-0.013846283
    ,-0.208462537,-0.027364528,-0.094725184,-0.238462548
    ,-0.391725489,-0.094725172)

    #Creamos la variable df1
    df1<-data.frame(a,b,repl,c,d)
    #Aqui estamos agrupando las columnas a, b y c y sacando el promedio de de sobre
    #esa agrupación
    df1 %>% group_by(a,b,c) %>%
            summarise(d=mean(d))

    # Groups:   a, b [4]
  a     b     c       d
 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.1    10     1 -0.0145
2   0.1    10     2 -0.398 
3   0.1   100     1  0.0250
4   0.1   100     2  0.0194
5   0.2    10     1 -0.201 
6   0.2    10     2 -0.0206
7   0.2   100     1 -0.243 
8   0.2   100     2 -0.167
```

Comment: Buen empleo del paquete `dplyr` si bien la OP no menciona que hay `Na` en la columna `d` para los ejemplos expuesto... sería interesante acotarlo en la respuesta, para futuras referencias.

Comment: Hola Hubert gracias por el comentario, tienes razón es importante considerar un escenario cuando existan Na, realizare la modificación. Saludos

Comment: @RUBENlopez muchas gracias!! me funcionó muy bien!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes también resolverlo con R base de una forma bastante compacta:

```
aggregate(d ~ a + b + c, df1, mean)
```

Con `aggregate()` agrupamos según la formula `d ~ a + b + c`, es decir agrupar por las tres primeras columnas y aplicamos sobre `d` la función `mean()`

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho un gusto. Tienes razón... esta es la forma más breve de obtener lo que pide la OP, quizás el dataframe `df1 <- aggregate(d ~ a + b + c, df1, mean)` se puede ordenar con `df1 <- df1[order(df1$a, df1$b),]`para corroborar con lo de @RUBEN lopez. Lo que no recuerdo bien es como saltar u omitir los `Na` cuando se emplea funciones anidadas en `aggregate` como `mean` en este caso

Comment: Hola @HubertRonald, con respecto a los `NA` `aggregate()` los ignora por defecto -> `na.action = na.omit`, lo otro sería como mantener los grupos que son únicamente `NA`, para eso esta el parámetro `drop=FALSE`. Saludos

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho! una forma más breve y sencilla. Muchas gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de obtener los resultados en R base manteniendo el orden que se requiere sería mediante la función `by` indicándose mediante una lista las columnas a agruparse

```
df <- read.table(text="
a    b   repl  c     d
0.1   10    1   1 -0.003278261
0.1   10    1   2 -0.303283860
0.1   10    2   1 -0.025801369
0.1   10    2   2 -0.493055524
0.1  100    1   1  0.022530623
0.1  100    1   2  0.018299374
0.1  100    2   1  0.027534172
0.1  100    2   2  0.020472938
0.2   10    1   1 -0.193742837
0.2   10    1   2 -0.013846283
0.2   10    2   1 -0.208462537
0.2   10    2   2 -0.027364528
0.2  100    1   1 -0.094725184
0.2  100    1   2 -0.238462548
0.2  100    2   1 -0.391725489
0.2  100    2   2 -0.094725172
", header = TRUE)

res <- by(df, list(df$a, df$b, df$c), function(x) data.frame(
  a = unique(x$a), # se requiere los elemento unicos de esta columnas a, b, c
  b = unique(x$b),
  c = unique(x$c),
  d = mean(x$d, na.rm=T)) # el promedio
)
```

`res` es del tipo lista `typeof(res)` para convertirlo en data frame se emplea la función `do.call` y luego mediante el método `order` se organiza el data frame requerido

```
df1 <- do.call(rbind, res)
df1 <- df1[order(df1$a, df1$b),] # se ordenan los elementos
df1
#     a   b c           d
# 1 0.1  10 1 -0.01453982
# 5 0.1  10 2 -0.39816969
# 3 0.1 100 1  0.02503240
# 7 0.1 100 2  0.01938616
# 2 0.2  10 1 -0.20110269
# 6 0.2  10 2 -0.02060541
# 4 0.2 100 1 -0.24322534
# 8 0.2 100 2 -0.16659386
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!